# SytaxError: invalid syntax on python test condition

Tags: python, syntax

I keep getting **SytaxError: invalid syntax** on my 2nd test condition (counter=1) in the python 3 code below.  I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.  Would appreciate a pointer.  Thanks

```
var="bubba"
final=var[0]
var2=tuple(var)
list=[]
counter=0
for each in var2:
    if each==final and counter=1:
        each= "H"
        counter=counter+1
        list.append(each)
    else:
        list.append(each)
        counter=counter+1
```

Comment: `=` is not `==`

Comment: For question like this - I would suggest that you run through interactive visual tool - `pythontutor.com` first. Then you can learn from the errors quickly. (then you can `debug` it first and point out where do you get stuck then ...)

Comment: I was going to suggest `pythontutor.com` too! Another good idea is to install a Python linter that checks the syntax of your program as you write it. Almost all decent and recent text editors and IDE can install such plugins, see for instance https://www.pylint.org/ . It would save you from such "easy" mistakes that are just errors of syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I see that the error `counter=1` is not the correct syntax. Since it's in an `if` statement, you will be comparing, not setting. Instead, on that line, it should be changed to:

```py
if each==final and counter==1:
```

It should be `==` not `=`.

---

## References

[`If Statements`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp)

Answer (score -1):

If you ware using Python version 3.8 or above, you could be interested to use the new "walrus" operator, `var := value`.
It allows to do like in C or Java, use the `value` of an assignment as a value itself, for tests or other things.

See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions the documentation if you are curious.